# Does anyone have aquifer depletion/recharge data for China, India, or any other country that isn't the United States?

Tags: data, metadata

Im doing a project for my capstone class in Geoenvironmental Studies and i am having a hard time finding data for aquifers in other countries.

Comment: FYI, see this current meta topic:
[Are questions about obtaining geospatial data on topic?](http://meta.gis.stackexchange.com/a/3577/753) In particular, [this answer](http://meta.gis.stackexchange.com/a/3577/753) suggests such questions should now be posed to the [Open Data Stack Exchange site](http://opendata.stackexchange.com/) (currently in beta), a position that I tend to agree with, but which has not yet been thoroughly discussed or decided.

Answer (score 1):

A note about GIS data from China; many (all) their datasets are considered national secrets and are very difficult to obtain. Even if you do obtain a copy you could get into trouble. I tried finding similar data for my capstone class and ran into the same problem.

If you are serious about working with GIS data in China, the easiest way is complete a masters program from a university within China.  There was a company out of Michigan (I think) that had some data on China, but they were restricted upon what data they could release.

Since no-one else has chimed-in, 
This paper may provide potential contact leads. 
http://landsat.gsfc.nasa.gov/?p=1273